# Max485 chip not working on 3v3 logic but able to work on 5v arduino pin even if only connected through my finger

Tags: c, arduino

I recently figured out how to reprogram the rfbees from seeedstudio. (a 3v3 xbee format rf module with onboard atmega168)
I want to port my existing DMX circuit to the rfbee.
I'm using a Max 485 chip to create dmx signals using this circuit http://fritzing.org/projects/arduino-to-dmx-converter/

This works perfectly on my arduino mega at 5v, however I've uploaded the same sketch to the rfbee but not getting any luck.
I realize the rfbee's pins only output 3v3 logic and the max485 is supposed to be 5v.

However, the 5v pin on the mega can still run the Max485 even if it is brought down to approx 3 volts by using three 220ohm resistors as voltage divider. I can also apparently drive the max485 by holding the 5v arduino pin with one hand and touching the input pin of the Max 485. The chip also seems perfectly happy having its Vin connected to the Mega's 3v3 pin instead of 5v.

My question is this, is there an electrical difference between these last approaches versus the clean 3v3 I'd be getting from the rfbee?
I'm using identical code on both devices with an LED to verify heartbeat. As far as I'm aware the pin I'm using (pin 5) is a pwm pin on both devices, http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/index.php?title=RFbee_V1.1_-_Wireless_Arduino_compatible_node .

I'm at a bit of a loss to know to check next, I've tested the output on pin 5 of both devices with an led (no oscilloscope unfortunately), both showed the same brightness and that it was an oscillating signal.

Code posted below.

```
#include <DmxSimple.h>
const byte DMX_RGB_CHANNELS[]={2, 3, 4};
const byte DMX_OUT_PIN=5;

int led = 13;


void setup() {                
 
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
  DmxSimple.usePin(DMX_OUT_PIN);
  DmxSimple.maxChannel(6); 

}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);  
  DmxSimple.write(DMX_RGB_CHANNELS[0], 255);
  DmxSimple.write(DMX_RGB_CHANNELS[1], 255);
  DmxSimple.write(DMX_RGB_CHANNELS[2], 255);
  delay(200);              
  
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);   
  DmxSimple.write(DMX_RGB_CHANNELS[0], 0);
  DmxSimple.write(DMX_RGB_CHANNELS[1], 0);
  DmxSimple.write(DMX_RGB_CHANNELS[2], 0);
  delay(200);              
}
```

Comment: isn't it an electrical / electronic question ? (though codes are posted, the focus is not on codes)

Comment: thanks, I've added a tag. I honestly don't know if it electrical or code, or possibly hardware!

Comment: Your resistor divider will not be able to supply as much current as a true 3.3v supply.  You should measure the voltage of your divider with the device plugged in and make sure there it isn't drooping.  If it is, use smaller resistor values

Comment: Thanks. But the voltage divider works, it's the 3.3v on the rfbee that isn't! I merely used the voltage divider to see if the Max 485 could work with a 3v signal. It appears that it does but I'm not sure if there isn't something else going on as well...j

Comment: signal are normally HIGH on RX bus. the mega/max485 have pin 5v compliant, but rfbees does not. Also rfbees  is 3V, not 3,3V.

you are at limit with the isteresis value normally used used (3v as logic 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, for some reason the atmega was running at half speed therefore the DMX baud rate was wrong. I was able to change the clock speed from 16MHz to 8Mhz in the boards.txt of the arduino compiler. Works now and the Max485 and RFbee seem to be working fine off just two AA batteries. It's been a long week!